# Power BI: Multiply by each point between two values. (Calculate Curve)

Tags: powerbi, dax

I'm working with a dataset where I have a Min Value and a Max value and then a sales value.

If the Min value = 100, the max value = 110 and the Sales value equal to 10. Then I have to create a line chart which plots the output of each number between the min and max multiplied by the sales value.

Which looks like below

[image: Which looks like below]

The goal is to create a line like below

[image: Which in turn generates a line such as the below]

Is there a way of doing this In Power BI via Dax as I am currently creating a mart table with a cursor for each record in the table containing the initial rows which is getting quite large?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create a (calculated) table like this:

```
Expanded_Data = 
GENERATE(
    'RawData';
    SELECTCOLUMNS(
        var maxMinusMin = [Max]-[Min]
        return
        GENERATESERIES(
            [Min]*maxMinusMin;
            [Max]*maxMinusMin;
            maxMinusMin
        );
        "Plot_Point"; [Value]
    )
)
```

Where `'RawData'` is the table name which has at least two columns named `[Max]` and `[Min]` :
[image][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pQUWc.png)

In this way you don't need the sales value info. Just substitute the variable for the sales value column